# Incremental learning with a built-in sagemaker algorithm

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, deep-learning, aws-sdk, amazon-sagemaker

I am training the DeepAR AWS SageMaker built-in algorithm. With the sagemaker SDK, I can train the model with particular specified hyper-parameters:

```
estimator = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    image_name=image_name,
    role=role,
    train_instance_count=1,
    train_instance_type='ml.c4.2xlarge',
    base_job_name='wfp-deepar',
    output_path=join(s3_path, 'output')
)

estimator.set_hyperparameters(**{
    'time_freq': 'M',
    'epochs': '50',
    'mini_batch_size': '96',
    'learning_rate': '1E-3',
    'context_length': '12',
    'dropout_rate': 0,
    'prediction_length': '12'
})

estimator.fit(inputs=data_channels, wait=True, job_name='wfp-deepar-job-level-5')
```

I would like to train the resulting model again with a **smaller learning rate**. I followed the incremental training method described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/sagemaker/latest/dg/incremental-training.html, but it does not work, apparently (according to the link), only two built-in models support incremental learning.

Has anyone found a workaround for this so that they can train a built-in algorithm with a scheduled learning rate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the SageMaker built-in DeepAR model doesn't support learning rate scheduling nor incremental learning.  If you want to implement learning rate plateau schedule on a DeepAR architecture I recommend to consider:

- using the open-source DeepAR implementation ([code](https://gluon-ts.mxnet.io/api/gluonts/gluonts.model.deepar.html), [demo](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/creating-neural-time-series-models-with-gluon-time-series/))
- or using the [DeepAR+ algo of the Amazon Forecast service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/forecast/latest/dg/aws-forecast-recipe-deeparplus.html), that features learning rate scheduling ability.